# Prove almost sure convergence related to i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I have following question and stuck at the 1st one.

> $\left\{X_n\right\}$ are i.i.d. random variables with non-zero finite mean. Let $S_n=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$. Prove
>   1. $|X_n|/n \xrightarrow{a.s.}0$;
>   2. $(\max_{1\le k \le n}|X_k|)/n \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$
>   3. $(\max_{1\le k \le n}|X_k|)/(1+S_n) \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$

I tried to use Borel-Cantelli lemma and Markov inequality, but failed.
**1st Try:** 
It's equivalent to show for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have $P(|X_n|/n > \epsilon \text{ i.o.})=0$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_n|/n > \epsilon) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E[|X_n|]/n\epsilon=\infty$$
I figured it didn't work probably because i.i.d. condition was not used.
**2nd Try**: $$\begin{align}P(|X_n|/n > \epsilon \text{ i.o.}) &= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}P(\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty |X_n|/n > \epsilon) \\ &= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}1-P((\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty |X_n|/n > \epsilon)^c) \\ &=\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}1-\prod_{n=m}^\infty P(|X_1|/n \le \epsilon)\end{align}$$ Stuck again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Markov inequaltiy is too weak in this case. Instead, use the fact that the $X_n$ are all identically distributed and the [integral comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Remark).

$$\sum \limits_{n = 1}^\infty P(|X_n|/n > \varepsilon) = \sum \limits_{n = 1}^\infty P(|X_1|/\varepsilon > n) \le 1 + \int_0^\infty P(|X_1|/\varepsilon > x) \, dx$$

Now note that for any nonnegative random variable $Y$ the equation
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty P(Y > x) \, dx &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty I\{y > x\} \, dP^Y(y) \, dx = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty I\{y > x\} \, dx \, dP^Y(y)\\
&= \int_0^\infty y \, dP^Y(y) = E[Y]
\end{align*}$$
holds.

Comment: Any idea on 2nd one? By a similar argument, I arrived $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1-P(|X_1|/\epsilon \le n)^n$$ How to show its convergence?

Comment: I don't know how to solve the other two.

Comment: The second one is very easy after you've proved the first one. What you need is just observing that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}nP(|X_1|>n\epsilon)=0$. For the third one, apply strong law of large numbers and invoke the consequence in 2.

Answer (score -4):

I guess following is the answer. 
$$\begin{align}P(|X_n|/n > \epsilon \text{ i.o.}) &= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}P(\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty |X_n|/n > \epsilon)\\ &= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}P(\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty |X_1|/n > \epsilon)\\ &= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}P(|X_1|/m > \epsilon) \\ & \le \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} E(|X_1|)/n \epsilon \rightarrow 0\end{align}$$

Comment: How could you arrive at the second equality?

Comment: Since $X_n$ are i.i.d, $$\left\{\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty |X_n|/n > \epsilon \right\}=\left\{\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty |X_1|/n > \epsilon \right\}=\left\{ |X_1|/m > \epsilon \right\}$$, the last equality is due to the fact  $$ \left \{ |X_1| / n > \epsilon \right \} \subset \left\{|X_1|/m > \epsilon \right\}$$ for any n > m

Comment: I think this is a correct answer. Why did I get 3 down-vote?

Comment: In your comment the first equality is wrong. We do _not_ have $\{|X_n|/n>\epsilon\}=\{|X_1|/n>\epsilon\}$.

Comment: Why is that? $X_1$ and $X_n$ have the same distribution.

Comment: The same distribution has nothing to do with $\{|X_n|/n>\epsilon\}=\{|X_1|/n>\epsilon\}$.

Comment: You are right in the sense. What I should do is add a probability measure in front.  $$P(\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty |X_n|/n > \epsilon) = P(\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty |X_1|/n > \epsilon) = P(|X_1|/m > \epsilon)$$

Comment: So how do you get $P(\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty |X_n|/n > \epsilon) = P(\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty |X_1|/n > \epsilon)$? You've never proved this is true. Of course, you can't make it since it's just not true.

Comment: @CaveJohnson You are right. I see your point. Many thanks.